# Laravel 5.3 NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:

Tags: laravel

I have a link on my page:

```
<a class="btn btn-default" href="/articles/{{ $article->id }}/edit">Edit</a>
```

and I have made route for it:

```
Route::get('/articles/{$articleId}/edit', 'ArticlesController@edit');
```

that leads to the function edit:

```
public function edit($articleId)
{
    dd($articleId);
    $article = Article::where('id', $articleId)->first();
}
```

but I get an error

```
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:
```

Not sure why do I get this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

error:

```
Route::get('/articles/{articleId}/edit', 'ArticlesController@edit');
```

articleId without $

Answer (score 0):

We can pass id like this

> Route::get('/articles/{articleId}/edit', 'ArticlesController@edit');

Remove $ symbol here